# What's the syntax for including ID and Class in the href query string?

Tags: html, query-string, href

I want something like this:

`href='home.php?ID'`

Do I include the hash for ID  or do I just call it as it as it is?

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you trying to use a CSS selector in a query string or something else?

Comment: was a bit confused, now i get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Id use this.

href='home.php?#ID'

Comment: and class should be this? href='home.php?.class' ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the hashkey. For example, on this page, [`#question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20628229/whats-the-syntax-for-including-id-and-class-in-the-href-query-string#question) will go directly on the div with the id "question"

Comment: And for class how do i write it?

Comment: @user3109875 - You cannot link to an element with a class. Remember that an ID should be unique in the page, but a class can appear multiple times.